# Powershell find common string in multiple files

Tags: regex, string, powershell

I found [PowerShell function that finds differences](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2013/11/29/using-powershell-to-compare-diff-files/) between files, but I am trying to find a function that finds common strings (i.e. common IP addresses) between the files.

I believe you can use `select-string`, but that would involve iterating over the first file, selecting the IP address as a regex pattern, and performing the select-string operation.

There has to be something more streamlined...

Comment: You're basically asking for an intersection of whole substring set of two different files. Perhaps you'd better first isolate the required substrings by regexp from each file into a separate array, and then plain call intersection [like here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/powershell/powershell-one-liners--collections,-hashtables,-arrays-and-strings/#third) to find out any common occurrences.

Comment: @Vesper Please answer followup question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604405/powershell-find-common-strings-varying-number-of-arrays