# Powershell find common strings varying number of arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell, intersection

Question is a follow up to [Powershell find common string in multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30598988/powershell-find-common-string-in-multiple-files)

Following PowerShell code

1. goes through a directory
2. for each file, extract IP addresses and store in multi-dimensional array `$match`
3. after iteration, go through each element in the multi-dimensional array and split by space, and store into another multi-dimensional array `$j`

I am able to find the intersection between `$j[0]` and `$j[1]`, but I'm not sure how to do this iteratively, over all the elements of `$j`, the array of IP address arrays.

See code

```
$i = $NULL
$match = @()
$j = @()
$input_path = $NULL
$output_file = "D:\Script\COMMON.TXT"

$directory = "D:\Script\Files"
$regex = ‘\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b’

Get-ChildItem $directory | ForEach-Object{

    $input_path = $directory + "\" + $_.Name
    write-host $input_path
    $match += ,@(select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value })
}



foreach ($i in $match){
    $j += ,@($i.split(" "))
}

$j[0] | sort | select -Unique | where {$j[1] -contains $_} | select -Unique > $output_file
```

Comment: It would've been better to update your previous question instead of posting a new one.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I was concerned about going off topic, because first question was about how to perform an intersection. Now that I know how to perform and intersection, I wish to know how to extend it to multiple arrays, where the number of arrays are unknown.

Comment: So you just want to find IPs common to all arrays in `$j`, regardless of how many arrays there are in `$j`?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician yes, that is correct, common IPs to all arrays in `$j`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy. You say you have two-dimensional array `$j` and want to find all strings that exist in all elements of `$j`. You create a temporary "total intersection" array out of `$j[0]` then run foreach on `$j` and create an intersection into that temporary. At the end it'll only contain those elements that all of the columns contain.

```
# $j is two-dimensional, and has unique elements
$t=$j[0]
$j | % {
    $i=$_ #rename to avoid confusion
    if ($i -ne $j[0]) { $t = $t|where {$i -contains $_}}
}
# $t now has your intersection
```

Comment: and since we are going through each element of `$j`, don't we need to append `$t`?

Comment: each file I am comparing is 20MB each, and the script has been running for past 30 minutes....

Comment: I've said, you should first extract IPs out of raw file, then run this against the 2-D array of IPs found. `%` is an alias for `ForEach-Object`, this means "for each element in `$j` do this code block". And no, appending `$t` is not needed, otherwise you'll not get an intersection but a complete `$j[0]` instead.